# How can an external event be known in one sub and not in another, in the same class?

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, event-handling, c#-to-vb.net

My question is probably best illustrated by the image.

In `Sub New`, `CompositionTarget.Rendering` is well known, but stuck with my throwback to C# syntax. VB.NET is hard! Yet in `CompositionTargetRendering`, the compiler has never come across it before. It's declared in `System.Windows.Media`, which I certainly have in my imports.

Is my declaration of the handler incorrect or something? Or is Xenu messing with me>

[image: Easiest way to explain.]

Oh yes, the C# I'm translating from compiles just fine:

```
    CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTargetRendering;
    private void CompositionTargetRendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > lastUpdateMilliSeconds + 5000)
        {
            viewModel.UpdateModel();
            Plot1.RefreshPlot(true);
            lastUpdateMilliSeconds = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't add handlers in VB.NET with `+=` you need to either:

Declare the object `WithEvents` and use the `Handles` keyword

```
Private WithEvents MyCompositionTarget As CompositionTarget

Private Sub CompositionTargetRendering() Handles MyCompositionTarget.Rendering
     'code for event here
End Sub
```

Or use `AddHandler` (which works in the same way as C# +=) (Don't use `Handles` keyword)

```
Private MyCompositionTarget As CompositionTarget

Publlic Sub New
    AddHandler MyCompositionTarget.Rendering, AddressOf CompositionTargetRendering
End Sub

Private Sub CompositionTargetRendering()
     'code for event here
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, I know; I said the += was a throwback to my C# comfort zone. I can't declare `CompositionTarget` `WithEvents`, it's an abstract class in `System.Windows.Media`. But thanks - I had forgotten about `AddHandler`, and now the compiler likes my code.